# Android Home button in collapsing toolbar with image

Tags: android, scroll, material-design, toolbar

I am looking to keep the home button in my toolbar. I have a collapsing toolbar with an image which disappears if scrolled up. In my other toolbar I implemented the tool bar with:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

but it doesn't work now. I can't see the button both when the toolbar is collapsed (when the image isn't shown) and when the toolbar is open (when the image is visible and the toolbar is expanded).

My Toolbar code:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.anim_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Awesome");
```

Comment: hi @user4789408 --- any solution found to this?

Answer (score 2):

You should put ToolBar in CollapsingToolbarLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505219/android-bug-home-button-in-toolbar-isnt-shown

Comment: what about the image?

Answer (score -2):

You can add navigation icon by,

```
   final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.nav_icon);
```

and you can specify the action in onOptionsItemSelected as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    final int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        //finish();
    }
 //........
}
```

Comment: This is not correct, because `onOptionsItemSelected` only works when using `setActionBar(toolbar)`. You have to add a listener to the toolbar if you want to use it this way